# How to use a dropdown to populate a list of post from CPT

Tags: widgets

I've created a widget that displays the latest posts from a dropdown of all the blog post types. I want to add an option for the user to choose a single post to be displayed as featured.

I would like that to happen after the user chooses their post type, a second dropdown will appear with list of all posts of this CPT, but I don't know how to populate it,

This is my widget code:

```
class custom_post_type  extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'custom_post_type', // Base ID
            __('Custom post type', ''), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Dispaly any CPT', '' ), ) // Args
        );

    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args ); 

    $link_url   = ($instance['url']);
    $types = empty($instance['types']) ? 'any' : explode(',', $instance['types']);

        echo $args['before_widget']; 

        $args = array(
        'post_type' => $types,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
      );

        global $post;
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        add_image_size( 'widget_homepage', 240, 180, false );       
        if($the_query->have_posts()) {
                while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                the_post_thumbnail($size = 'widget_homepage');
                echo '<h4 class="title">';
                    the_title();
                echo '</h4>';
                echo '<div class="date">';
                    the_date();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<p>'; 
                echo excerpt(25); 
                echo '</p>'; ?>
                <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php 
                _e('Read More','lookstein'); 
                echo '</a>';            }    
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo '<p style="padding:25px;">No listing found</p>';
        }

        echo $after_widget;
    }


    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {

      // Set default arguments
      $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array(
        'types' => 'post',

      ) );

      // Or use the instance
      $types  = $instance['types'];


      // Let's turn $types, $cats, and $tags into an array if they are set
      if (!empty($types)) $types = explode(',', $types);

      // Count number of post types for select box sizing
      $cpt_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'names' );
      if ($cpt_types) {
        foreach ($cpt_types as $cpt ) {
          $cpt_ar[] = $cpt;
        }
        $n = count($cpt_ar);
        if($n > 6) { $n = 6; }
      } else {
        $n = 3;
      }

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'url' ] ) ) {
            $link_url = $instance[ 'url' ];
        }
        else {
            $link_url = __( '#', 'lookstein' );
        }

        ?>

        <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('types'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Post types', 'upw' ); ?>:</label>
          <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('types'); ?>[]" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('types'); ?>" class="widefat" style="height: auto;" size="<?php echo $n ?>" multiple>
            <option value="" <?php if (empty($types)) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('&ndash; Show All &ndash;') ?></option>
            <?php
            $args = array( 'public' => true );
            $post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' );
            foreach ($post_types as $post_type ) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" <?php if(is_array($types) && in_array($post_type, $types)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $post_type;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'url' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Button URL:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'url' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'url' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_url ); ?>">

        </p>


        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {        

        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['url'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['url'] );
        $instance['types'] = (isset( $new_instance['types'] )) ? implode(',', (array) $new_instance['types']) : '';

        return $instance;

    }

} // end widget class RSS
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX to populate your data. There's a ton of tutorials online which go over it, [here's a nice one](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/).